# How to restrict automatically inserting text to view when selecting a item from drop down menu Android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, adapter, onitemclicklistener

I am working on `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`. This view has a `ArrayAdapter`.

Like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);

final MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = 
            (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And drop down menu:

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[]{
            "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"};
```

User may select a item from drop down menu shown by some text user typed. at that time, the text user typed is replaced by selected item.

I want to know where this replacement is implemented or how to restrict this replacement. because when user select item, i want to insert text of selected item with additional text to `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`. (e.g., change "Belgium" to "I Love Belgium")

I can get selected item's string in `OnItemClickListener`. so try to change.

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position < 0) {
            return;
        }

        // get selected item string
        String selItem = (String) textView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

        // find text user typed
        Editable editable = textView.getText();
        int end = textView.getSelectionEnd();
        int start = mTokenizer.findTokenStart(editable, end);

        // i want to change like this..
        String str = "I Love ";
        str += TextUtils.substring(editable, start, end);

        // replace text user typed by selected Item
        editable.replace(start, end, str);
    }
});
```

I expect the result is "I Love Belgium" only. But the result is "Belgium, I Love Belgium, ". I want to know where this replacement is implemented or how to restrict this replacement.